# How to save a dataframe to csv in Azure datalake in the specified folder using databricks utilities (dbutils)

Tags: python, pandas, azure, azure-data-lake

I have a dataframe called data and I am saving it as csv file into my datalake using pandas.to_csv. However it is taking lot of time to save the files to csv . Can anyone please tell me how to save the csv files to datalake using dbutils ?? Also, please confirm whether the code to create directory (if it does not exist) is correct or not

```
d = data.groupby(['Col1', 'Col2'])
for k, Dates in d:
    if not Dates.empty:
        PATH = /dbfs/mnt/data/../'
        try:
            dbutils.fs.ls(PATH)                      
            pass
        except Exception as e:
            if 'java.io.FileNotFoundException' in str(e):
                dbutils.fs.mkdirs(PATH)                              
        Dates.to_csv(PATH+f'{Day}.csv',index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

In dbutils there is only coalesce and partition methods for saving files to csv and they will create files with Random names to create files in required names we use pandas to_csv method

**Method 1**

1. From Azure Databricks home, you can go to “Upload Data” (under Common Tasks) → “DBFS” → “FileStore”.
2. I created a folder “df” and saved a data frame “Sample” into CSV. It is important to use coalesce(1) since it saves the data frame as a whole.
   [image]

```
Sample.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header","true").save("dbfs:/FileStore/df/Sample.csv")
```

3. The “part-00000” is the CSV file
   [image]
4. Download file to local and rename if required
   [image]
5. Upload the csv file manually to datalake storage as follows
   [image]

**Method 2**

1. Data in the DBFS Databricks File System

```
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("recursiveFileLookup", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").option("header", "true").load("dbfs:/myfolder/sample/")
df.show()
```

[image]

2. Configure storage account access key globally

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net", "<<ACCESS KEY>>")
```

3. Configure storage account folder

```
 output_container_path = "abfss://<<filesystem>>@<<Storage_Name>>.dfs.core.windows.net/<<DirectoryName>>"
 output_blob_folder = "%s/CSV_data_folder" % output_container_path
```

4. write the dataframe as a single csv file to storage

```
 (df
    .coalesce(1)
    .write
    .mode("overwrite")
    .option("header", "true")
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .save(output_blob_folder))
```

[image]

5. Uploaded file in storage
   [image]